# React/Flux - Best way to monitor api and update store on new data?

Tags: javascript, rest, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I'm trying to figure out how to update store when api returns changed data.
One of my Components is supposed to render "live" data when other users write data to api. What's the best approach? Poll async data on interval?

I'm using ReactJS/AltJS and right now i'm using jQuery for making async api calls in my Actions.

Thanks!

BookActions.js:

```
getBook(bookId) {
  $.ajax({ url: '/api/books/' + bookId })
    .done((data) => {
      this.actions.getBookSuccess(data);
    })
    .fail((jqXhr) => {
      this.actions.getBookFail(jqXhr);
    });
}
```

BookStore.js

```
import alt from '../alt';
import BookActions from '../actions/BookActions';

class BookStore {
  constructor() {
    this.bindActions(BookActions);
    this.books = [];
  }

  onGetBookSuccess(data) {
    this.books = data;
  }

  onGetBookFail(errorMessage) {
    toastr.error(errorMessage);
  }

}

export default alt.createStore(BookStore);
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, what you are trying to do. You state that you poll async data on interval, but I see you do this only in getBook method (maybe you are calling it on interval?). What kind of data are stored in book data? Do they change frequently? If not than it's perfectly ok to fetch data on componentDidMount. if it changes frequently than you should consider some sort of data push model.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have to define what's 'live' data. After a user write some data to the server, how long can you wait until you know there's new data? If you want to be notified within 1 second, you also need to design your backend system carefully.

In your question, I assume that several seconds delay are tolerable. One of the simple solutions is polling. According to the [react doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount), you can create a timer in `componentDidMount` to invoke the API periodically, and clean up everything in `componentWillUnmount`.

Don't put the timer logic into the actions which may be shared by man components.